# How to get file upload in Nuxt 3 server api?

Tags: nuxtjs3

server/api/customers.post.ts

```
import { readBody } from 'h3'

export default defineEventHandler(async (event): Promise<any> => {
  const body: any = await readBody(event)

  return { data: body }
})
```

When I test on postman for upload profile image then I got the response:
[image]

How to get file for upload to server?
Thank you

Comment: Where or how do you want to save this file?

Comment: I want upload to supabase storage.